# extract a sub-Panel from a Panel in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panel:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 5 (items) x 6 (major_axis) x 10 (minor_axis)
Items axis: alpha= 00.0 to alpha= 14.0
Major_axis axis: 0 to 5
Minor_axis axis: Ca force to force
```

In each Panel['alpha= xx.x'] I have a field named 'force' (which is not the index).

How can i extract from the Panel a sub-Panel selecting only (for example) ['alpha= 00.0','alpha= 02.0'] and all the rows where force is in [0.0,1000.,]?

Edit:

```
>>>Panel.items
Index([u'alpha= 02.0', u'alpha= 04.0', u'alpha= 06.0', u'alpha= 08.0', u'alpha= 10.0', u'alpha= 12.0', u'alpha= 13.0', u'alpha= 14.0'])

>>>Panel['alpha= 06.0'] #and all other DataFrame are similar
     Cn tot  Force
0  0.745853      0
1  0.836990    500
2  0.912409   1000
3  1.033221   2000
4  1.581379  10000
5  1.825051  15000
```

This is the situation. What I want, is to create a new Panel such that,for exalple:

```
>>> Panel_new.items
Index(['alpha= 06.0', u'alpha= 10.0'])

>>>Panel_new['alpha= 06.0'] # #and all other DataFrame are similar
     Cn tot  Force
0  0.745853      0
1  0.912409   1000
```

Let me know if it is clear or not.

Comment: can you show what you are expecting for a result? selecting 'rows' on a panel doesn't make sense (you mean minor-axis right?)

Comment: Make sure your example explains what you mean by `force is in [0.0, 1000.]` I've got a solution that works by slicing on the index labels, but you may want to slice according actual values.

Answer (score 0):

subidx = ['alpha= 06.0', 'alpha= 10.0']

Panel_new= Panel.ix[subidx]

This should work for you